# Film maker “Cat Vindaloo” trying to make a Bollywood film on the Moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I'm pretty sure this isn't false memory syndrome, but as a kid I frequently read scifi anthologies from my local library in the late 60's & amongst many others, one story has always stuck with me - it was a story featuring a futuristic Indian film maker called "Cat Vindaloo", trying to make "Bollywood" film on the Moon - beyond that & the ludicrous (& funny) name I can't remember much else.

Anyone else recall this short story & the anthology it featured in – it was definitely in the older reader section of the library's' scifi section.

Comment: Cat Vindaloo you say? I must try that one day.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Rimmer would probably approve! (I just busted a gut roflmao when I saw your comment)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a very old post, but I believe this might be "[A Taste for Dostoevsky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?67245)" by Brian Aldiss.

> Looking up, he saw that a solitary figure stood on a ridge of rock, staring moodily up at the fake heavens. He identified it as Cat Vindaloo, the Pakistani director of their show, and called a greeting to him.
>  
> Cat nodded sourly and altered his position without actually coming any nearer to Moore.
>  
> “We went over well tonight,” Moore said.
>  
> “They still pay to come and watch,” Cat said.
>  
> “Your trouble is, you’re obsessed with being a failure, Cat. Come on, snap out of it. If there’s anything wrong with the show, it is that it’s too realistic. I’d personally like to see less of a dying fall to end with—maybe a grand finale such as they’d have had at the end of last century, with all the crew parading outside the ship, taking a bow.”

Seems like a relatively rare story.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in a quote

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's been bugging me for ages and I only stumbled on this yesterday (23rd May 2018) after totally forgetting that I'd posted the question in the first place. And yes, "Cat Vindaloo" features at the very start - he's a Pakistani film producer making a film on the Moon sometime in the future.

Comment: Hi there! (hi again, should  I say!) Glad you found it, however this should be posted as a comment - you may have forgotten your old account's login info, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to join both accounts. See you! :)

Comment: And once you've reclaimed your old account, you can accept Otis's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I'm glad it turned out to be correct, and welcome back. Credit to Valorum for the supporting quote.